# Unable to load DLL,wrong location?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web, fortran

I have made a website with Visual Studio 2010. I have a simple Fortran .dll that I want to call from my project. I have added this DLL in my project but when I run it I get the error:

> Unable to load DLL 'Dll1.dll': The specified module could not be found.

which probably means that the DLL can not be found. Do I have to add the .dll somewhere specifically or add the location of the DLL to the code?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the dll file, click on properties, then in the properties pane below the solution explorer, set "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy Always".

Comment: Property "Copy to Output Directory" doesn't appear when i select the dll

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Dll1.dll is the DLL that is one that's referenced, make sure that in Solution Explorer, this DLLs properties are set to Copy Always.